# Problem to publish "You have uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that can be debugged."

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am publishing an app and it throws me the following error:

**You have uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that can be debugged.**

It asks me to put this in the manifest.xml file and I already did it

```
android:debuggable="false"
```

And in what part of the application should this be put:

```
#if DEBUG
  [Application (Debuggable = true)]
#else
  [Application (Debuggable = false)]
#endif
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you have debugging enabled in the Android build settings?

Comment: You could try the way: Android Project> Properties> Android Options> Debugging Options> uncheck to disable.